# Odd Face Icon Appearing in iPhone App when localizing in Chinese

Tags: iphone, localization

I'm localizing my English app into Traditional and Simplified Chinese and right now, the English looks fine. However, when I switch to Chinese, in some area, I get these weird faces which look like a guy's face with the word "Insanitype" underneath it. I realized it only happens when I use this:

```
[lblName setText:[NSLocalizedString(@"menuHello",@"") stringByAppendingString:[ NSString stringWithFormat:@", %@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"bluebaymob.amazingABC.nombre"]]]];
```

So whenever I use this line again:

```
[lblName setText:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"bluebaymob.amazingABC.nombre"]];
```

The faces appear. Anyone else with this problem? Thank you for helping!

UPDATE: Screen shot

Here this link since I can't post yet: http://i.imgur.com/so7YL.jpg

The odd faces are in the upper left-hand corner.

Comment: I was thinking emoji, but they don't have long english words associated with them. Can you show us a screenshot?

Comment: Also, are you using a custom font? Insanitype is the name of a font foundry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using a custom font: BradBunR and it did not support Chinese characters. I just switched to another

```
NSLocalized(@"font",@"");
```

and then in my chinese files used Arial or some other system font. Thanks for helping!